# Change array structure in PHP

Tags: php, prado

Refers to my previous question : Show values in TDropDownList in PRADO.
ok fine the array i receive from query is an object array like :

```
ContactRecord Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => leo [_recordState:protected] => 1 [_connection:protected] => [_invalidFinderResult:protected] => [_e:TComponent:private] => Array ( ) )
ContactRecord Object ( [id] => 2 [name] => ganda [_recordState:protected] => 1 [_connection:protected] => [_invalidFinderResult:protected] => [_e:TComponent:private] => Array ( ) )
```

If I convert it in to array like:

```
Array ( [key 1] => leo [key 2] => ganda )
```

then I can populate values into TDropDownList.

Now can anyone help me to convert array structure which I need ... ?

Again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the keys:

```
array_map(function (ContactRecord $o) { return $o->name; }, $origArray)
```

Otherwise:

```
$res = array();
foreach ($origArray as $obj) {
    $res[$o->id] = $o->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, `foreach` in PHP works with objects as well. try the following:

```
$ret = array();
foreach ($object as $val) $ret[] = $val;
```

also, you can retrieve a property in PHP as `$object->$propertyName`. so if you can get hold of the property names, you just loop through them, retrieve the values and push them to an array.

greetz
back2dos